# XCode archive not including files in referenced folder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm having a hard time producing an Archive for my project. I can run fine on my device and in the simulator. I have several resources that I am referencing in a folder that I added as a reference. The folder has been added to my bundle resources and before I copy bundle resources I'm executing a script to touch the folder.

However when the archive is produced, it's practically empty (2 KB) when it should be around 14-16 MB. There are no errors and the Archive validates fine. It error on trying to distribute, but beyond that I'm seeing no issues. It's like it isn't actually packaging anything up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. I had a file in my referenced folder named:

```
._app.properties
```

And another named:

```
._.DS_Store
```

Apparently any file in your referenced resources with a name starting with ._ or _ will cause an issue.